# mysql sum() two tables

Tags: mysql, sum

I have been working on this and am having a hard time.

The code that I am using is

```
 SELECT 
      employee.vorname, employee.emp_nr, SUM(az_konto.az) AS Total
    FROM 
      employee, az_konto 
    WHERE  
      az_konto.datum BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-01' + 
      INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND 
      `employee`.`emp_nr` = `az_konto`.`emp_nr`
    GROUP BY 
      vorname, emp_nr, az
```

The result that I am getting is:

```
Frank    01   0.00
Frank    01   4.92
Janine   47   6.69
Janine   47   5.25
Julianne 57   0.18
```

What I am trying to get is

```
Frank       01  4.92
Janine      47  11.94
Julianne    57  0.18
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: Please give an example of a join. I have tried many different and always have a syntax error.  Either the WHERE is a problem or the GROUP BY

Comment: `FROM employee JOIN az_konto ON employee.emp_nr = az_konto.emp_nr`. The rest of the query stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many columns in the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT employee.vorname, employee.emp_nr, SUM(az_konto.az) AS Total
FROM employee, az_konto 
WHERE ( az_konto.datum BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-01' + 
INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND `employee`.`emp_nr` = `az_konto`.`emp_nr`)
GROUP BY vorname, emp_nr
```

With `JOIN` syntax

```
SELECT e.vorname, e.emp_nr, SUM(a.az) AS Total
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN az_konto a ON a.emp_nr = e.emp_nr
WHERE a.datum BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY e.vorname, e.emp_nr
```

Comment: With `JOIN`, all the join condition is in the `JOIN` clause, so it will not mixed with your `WHERE` condition.  When you have 5+ table join, it will be hard to read when your `WHERE` clause also contains your join condition.